# How to get the text value from Multiline text field in sharepoint using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I tried this code:

```
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite("http://omar:2020/Lists/Calendar1/AllItems.aspx"))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["Calendar"];
        SPListItem item = oList.GetItemById(7);

        txtArea_desc.InnerText = item["Description"].ToString();

    }
}
```

But it gave me "class="ExternalClassD6E6296DE90F457892C156ABE9631AC6Hello"
in the TextArea.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What type of class is `txtArea_desc`?

Answer (score 3):

`Description` field in `Event` content type has the following declaration:

```
<Field ID="{9da97a8a-1da5-4a77-98d3-4bc10456e700}"
    Type="Note"
    RichText="TRUE"
    Name="Comments"
    Group="_Hidden"
    DisplayName="$Resources:core,Comments;"
    Sortable="FALSE"
    SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
    StaticName="Comments">
</Field>
```

Since `RichText` attribute is set to true, it's value contains html content.

Use [SPField.GetFieldValueAsText Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getfieldvalueastext(v=office.14).aspx) to get the field value as *plain text*.

**Example**

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        var list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listTitle);
        var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
        var eventDescField = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Description");
        var eventDesc = item[eventDescField.Id];
        var eventDescText = eventDescField.GetFieldValueAsText(eventDesc);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your multiline-text field must be in gross text mode in the settings, if not you will have the css class like your example